# "Type variable-sized object may not be initialized" when creating a array in a struct (C language)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have to create an array in a struct and add different values each time the program receive a  SIGUSR1 signal.

This is the code

```
if (signo == SIGUSR1){
    signal(SIGUSR1, NewUser);
    if (NewUser()<11){
        i++;
        struct users user[i] = {i,0,count};
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, (void*)Actions, &user);
    }
```

(I receive "count" from "NewUser()")

"users" is a global variable, where is the problem and how can i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You say `users` is a global variable. Where did you define `user[]`? Note - no `s` at the end.

Comment: `users` according to this code isn't a global variable; its a *type*. `user` is the variable (a variable-length array of length `i`). The error is because you can't provide an initializer for a VLA.

Comment: I hope you are not trying to run this code from the signal handler because `pthread_create()` is not async safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correction...

```
user[i] = (struct user){i,0,count};
```

When you type `struct users user[i] = ...` you are declaring a *new variable* instead of assigning a value to an existing global variable.